# Enqueue function to execute after currently running function is done executing (setTimeout)

Tags: javascript, html

I have a basic timer where a user puts in a number, then it counts down until it hits 0.

I want the user to put another number while the timer for the prev is still going on. When the timer for the prev number hits 0, a new timer for the recently entered number will begin. My code somehow has both timers running concurrently despite my uses of `setInterval` and `setTimeout`.

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
  </head>
  <script>
    var isRunning = false;
    var qNums = [];

    var wrapFunction = function (fn, context, params) {
      return function () {
        fn.apply(context, params);
      };
    };

    function q() {
      var sec = document.getElementById("data").value;
      if (!Number.isInteger(parseInt(sec))) {
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Not a number!";
        return;
      } else if (parseInt(sec) < 0) {
        document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Invalid timer setting!";
        return;
      }
      qNums.push(wrapFunction(countDown, this, [sec]));

      while (qNums) {
        qNums.shift()();
      }
    }

    function countDown(sec) {
      var sec = document.getElementById("data").value;
      var ms = 100;
      isRunning = true;
      document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "";
      document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML = "Ticking!";
      var interval = setInterval(function () {
        if (ms == 100) {
          document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = sec + ".00";
        } else {
          document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = sec + "." + ms;
        }
        ms -= 10;
        if (ms < 0) {
          sec--;
          ms = 100;
        }
        if (sec < 0) {
          document.getElementById("data").value = "";
          document.getElementById("btn").innerHTML = "Start";
          document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = "Countdown complete";
          isRunning = false;
          clearInterval(interval);
        }
      }, 100);
    }
  </script>
  <body>
    <h1>Timer</h1>
    <label>Timer Duration: </label><input id="data" />
    <button id="btn" onclick="countDown()">Start</button>
    <p id="timer"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

`q()` is my awful attempt at trying to implement this. `countDown()` is the standalone implementation of the countdown, separate from this functionality.

EDIT: Why does the snippet not run my code but the browser does???? Not sure how to fix this

Comment: do you want to use the same input for both timers?

Answer (score 0):

Good try, but each interval has no way of triggering the next one to start with a callback, and without that, they'll all run concurrently. Pass the `q.shift()()` in as a callback to the timer function which can be invoked when the timer runs out alongside `clearTimeout`, or write a loop and only run the 0-th timer if it exists.

Another problem: `setTimeout` is often mistaken to be perfectly accurate, but this is an incorrect assumption. The `ms` parameter only guarantees the timer will be invoked no sooner than the duration specified. The consequence of this is that it will accumulate drift. A more accurate approach is to use a date object to check the system's time.

Here's a proof-of-concept using the polling version:

```js
const enqueueTimer = () => {
  const sec = +els.data.value;

  if (!Number.isInteger(sec)) {
    els.timer.innerHTML = "Not a number!";
  }
  else if (sec < 0) {
    els.timer.innerHTML = "Invalid timer setting!";
  }
  else {
    timers.push({duration: sec * 1000});
  }
};

const updateTimers = () => {
  if (!timers.length) {
    return;
  }

  const {duration, start} = timers[0];
  const now = new Date();

  if (!start) {
    timers[0].start = now;
  }

  const elapsed = now - start || 0;
  const remaining = duration - elapsed || 0;
  const sec = remaining / 1000;
  const ms = remaining % 1000;
  els.timer.innerHTML = `${~~sec}.${("" + ms)
    .slice(0, 2).padEnd(2)}`;
  els.btn.innerHTML = "Ticking!";

  if (elapsed >= duration) {
    timers.shift();

    if (timers.length) {
      timers[0].start = new Date(start.getTime() + duration);
    }
    else {
      els.data.value = "";
      els.btn.innerHTML = "Start";
      els.timer.innerHTML = "Countdown complete";
    }
  }
};

const els = {
  btn: document.getElementById("btn"),
  data: document.getElementById("data"),
  timer: document.getElementById("timer"),
};
els.btn.addEventListener("click", enqueueTimer);
const timers = [];
setInterval(updateTimers, 100);
```

```html
<h1>Timer</h1>
<label>Timer Duration: <input id="data" /></label>
<button id="btn">Start</button>
<p id="timer"></p>
```

If it bothers you that the interval always runs, feel free to save the interval id, add a `clearInterval()` on the id when all the timers expire and kick off a new interval when a fresh timer is created.